# Bootstrap wysihtml5 editor - can't insert html using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to insert some HTML (html_string) into the textarea using:

```
var editorElement = $("#my_textarea").wysihtml5();
var wysihtml5Editor = editorElement.data("wysihtml5").editor;
wysihtml5Editor.composer.commands.exec("insertHTML", html_string);
```

However, this only seems to work if I have first clicked on the textarea at least once. Has anyone else seen this? (the JS debugger yields no errors).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$("#my_textarea").val(html_string);
```

Alternatively also try after your code:

```
editorElement.data("wysihtml5").editor = wysihtml5Editor;
```

Can you make a JSFiddle?